# IDLE, State Transfer Status

Tags: replication, infinispan

According to documentation for state transfer status (https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/xsite/xsite.html#rest_v2_xsite_state_push) there're only 4 states:

SENDING,OK,ERROR,CANCELLING

But i'm getting a IDLE state for this request
http://IP:11222/rest/v2/caches/CACHE_NAME/x-site/backups?action=push-state-status
{
"NODE_11": "IDLE"
}

What represents this state? After starting a new transfer, everything seems to be replicated and the node is in OK state.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The table in the documentation is incomplete.

IDLE is the state before any state transfer has been started, or after the state transfer status has been cleared with

```
POST /v2/caches/{cacheName}/x-site/local?action=clear-push-state-status
```